# Howto Save App data to File on program crash

Tags: vb.net

I have a program where the user inputs data, but every now and then the program crashes for unforeseen reasons. I'm re-coding to fix the errors as they surface, but I would like to prevent the user from losing any unsaved work when the crash occurs. 
I've designed a solution that autosaves to a file every hour, but...

Is there a way to save app data to a file before it force closes after the Error Window?

What is the standard method of handling these situations?
Thank you for reading my Question =]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of crash, you may not have any control of it, so your program may not be given a chance to gracefully fail. In this case you need to be logging all "important" user activity, as they work through.

If you notice all users suddenly fail on or near Action A, then Action A is most likely the cause of the error. Or it could be specific time of day, in which backups run, for example.

By analyzing average duration of operations, you may find that before your app fails, duration is increased. This could lead you to memory leaks or CPU bottlenecks.

Based on what you find, you may add more detailed logging for Action A, or try something else. It's hard to say without knowing the nature of your application.

Comment: It's basically an addressbook with text fields and comboboxes data is stored in an array of structure. Most of the crashes are from index problems and multiple edit windows open that conflict.

Comment: @WilliamMorschauser: If they are not external, you should put a `Try...Catch` around all places, where you expect an error. Also put a [global handler](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.ca/2013/03/gotta-catch-em-all-last-chance.html) for those unexpected scenarios. You can log any useful information before shutting down the app in this case. Ideally of course fix the error after reviewing the logs or going several times through your code to make sure it does what it's supposed to.